# Unity ARFoundation - Augmented Objects does not register collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, collision, android-augmented-reality

I'm currently stuck with my remote control app in terms of collisions.
I'm using Arcore XR plugin and AR Foundation.

I've placed a building and added mesh collider on it and my car.
My car has a rigidbody component so when I play it in the editor the car stops when hitting the building as intended.
However, when building the app to my android device it just drives through it as if there were no colliders/as if my phone has no collisipn dtection.

I've tried adding rigidbody on my building and ticking on and off convex.

Right now I'm out of ideas.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

If you're experiencing the same problems, if you've imported any FBX file, make sure to have Read/Write enabled.

Go to your Project Folder in Unity, find your .fbx models and click on it.
Then in the inspector, click Model then make sure that Read/Write is enabled.

Mesh Colliders should now work.